# How to get select attribute in angular 6

Tags: angular, attributes, angular6, html-select

I tried below code to get the value of data attribute of country but does not worked.

```js
  fieldId: target.getAttribute('data-country_id'),
   const selectEl = event.target;
   var id = angular.element(event).data('country_id');
  console.log("test"+event.currentTarget.getAttribute("data-id"));
```

```html
  <select name="state"  [(ngModel)]="model.state"  id="state"  (ngModelChange)="GetCitySelected($event)" >
  <option *ngFor="let state of StateList" value="{{state.id}}" [attr.data-country_id]="state.country_id">{{state.name}}</option>
   </select>
```

Comment: why not pass the value in the function? `(ngModelChange)="GetCitySelected($event,state.country_id)"`

Comment: Another Idea is that `countryId=StateList.find(x=>x.id==model.state).country_id`

Answer (score 3):

You need selected option index to get attribute value of selected option.

**Html**

```
<select name="state" [(ngModel)]="model.state" (change)="stateChange($event)"  id="state">
  <option *ngFor="let state of StateList" [value]="state.id" [attr.data-country_id]="state.country_id">{{state.name}}</option>
</select>
```

**Component**

```
stateChange(event){
    let selectedIndex:number = event.target["selectedIndex"];
    console.log(event.target.options[selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-country_id"))
}
```

I used (change) event instead of (ngModelChange) for your solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with **`[value]`** binding with **`ngModel`**.

```
 <select name="state"  [(ngModel)]="model.state"  id="state"  (ngModelChange)="GetCitySelected($event)" >
      <option *ngFor="let state of StateList" [value]="state" [attr.data-country_id]="state.country_id">{{state.name}}</option>
 </select>
```

here you need to match the data of `value` attribute with `ngModel` variable.

Comment: ping me if you want any help further.. :)